# Taylor series loop

Tags: polynomials, series-expansion

I'm a beginner not only in Mathematica but also in programming in general, and so I'm not really sure where my problem lies exactly and I'd be glad to receive any guidance.

Using the Taylor series for arctan(x) I want to write a scrap of code that will find the approximate value at Pi/4 by increasing the degree of the Taylor polynomial until a certain precision threshold is reached. This is what I have so far:

```
g6[x_, n_] := Evaluate[Normal[Series[ArcTan[x], {x, 0, n}]]]
n = 1;
x1 = Pi/4;
epsilon = 10^-2;

While[Abs[ArcTan[x1] - g6[x1, n]] > epsilon, 
n++];
Print["n = ", n];
```

This isn't working and I am **fuming** because it is such a deplorably short piece of code and I have altered it multiple times, including wrapping some of the expressions in "N[..", changing the order of declaration of the variables, "translating" the n value to specifically integer form, delaying the evaluation of the function, *ReplaceAll*, the *SeriesCoefficient* function to first calculate the coefficients before computing the value for x1, and also quitting kernels, switching back and forth between the cloud and the installed version, and restarting the whole lot (my Mathematica tends to say there are errors in the code, whereas sometimes the code itself is not the issue at all) and so I am disconsolate at best, and out of ideas.

I am eager to resolve this issue, since I have to know what's wrong in order to solve similar problems that are more complicated and require precision up to 10^-17, so it would help me a lot to recognize whether the problem lies in my programming thinking (or lack thereof) or my still very slowly improving unaquaintance with Mathematica.

Also, I know what the n value should be, but I cannot use the trial and error method here and should be able to solve this using nothing more advanced than functions like *Series, Normal, SeriesCoefficient* and *Evaluate*.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yagotta take the series in a variable and then substitute a value. Pi/4 is your constant and cannot be that variable. This works. `g6[x_, x0_, n_] := Normal[Series[ArcTan[x], {x, 0, n}]] /. x -> x0
n = 1;
x1 = Pi/4;
epsilon = 10^-2;
While[Abs[ArcTan[x1] - g6[x, x1, n]] > epsilon, n++];
Print["n = ", n];

n = 7`